# Blending modes across different compositions in After Effects

Tags: adobe-after-effects

It seems that the blending mode that I set to multiply on the shape layer of a composition in After Effects is not interacting with the composition directly beneath it on the master composition.

The Beech Tween 24 frame comp has a shadow layer at the bottom of it set to multiply. It appears that the layer is just coming in as normal. Eg it doesnt interact with the Mountains and Sky comp.

Is there any way to make this happen?

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screen capture? It is not clear.

Comment: Thanks Rafael. The Beech Tween 24 frame comp has a shadow layer at the bottom of it set to multiply. It appears that the layer is just coming in as normal. Eg it doesnt interact with the Mountains and Sky comp which is disappointing. Maybe there is a way around it.

Comment: Blending modes only work inside one composition. You'll have to separate shadow and character into two comps and them multiply the shadow comp/shape